# Keep.both example in Akka Stream

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I would like to understand the `Keep.both` in akka stream but I could not find an easy on the internet.

Could someone please provide a very simple example about `Keep.right` and `Keep.both`.

I tried:

```
   implicit val system = ActorSystem("KafkaProducer")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val source = Source.single("Hello")_
    val sink = Sink.fold[String, String]("")(_ + _)

    val runnable: RunnableGraph[Future[String]] = source.toMat(sink)(Keep.left)
    runnable.run()
```

I know, it is maybe not a good example and hopefully, someone provide a better example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Via/ViaMat/to/toMat in Akka Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911174/via-viamat-to-tomat-in-akka-stream)

Comment: There's a pretty good section on it in Akka Streams docs. See: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-composition.html#materialized-values

Comment: It has nothing to do with Kafka Stream, you should change your title.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest scenario, you need a stream to process a bunch of elements that you are going to (1) provide from outside the stream and you need to know when the (2) stream finish processing all elements.

For (1) you could use a `Source.queue` that is materialized into a queue and you can push elements to it via offer.

```
val source = Source.queue[String](100,OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
```

For (2) you could use a `Sink.foreach` that is materialized into a `Future[Done]` *which will be completed with `Success` when reaching the normal end of the stream, or completed with `Failure` if there is a failure signaled in the stream.*

```
val sink = Sink.foreach[String](println)
```

Then you need to connect source and sink and **Keep.both** materialized values.

```
val materializedValues: (SourceQueueWithComplete[String], Future[Done]) = source.toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()
```